# force correct date format in a userform in vba

Tags: vba

I have the date set to the format 29/8/2023 in the general settings on a mac.
I am using excel 2016 and have a userform where a date is entered into a text box.

I have tried various ways to check that the  date entered is in the format dd/mmm/yy

I want to trap all errors so that the userform is not closed before a correct date is entered.

I can get most of the way using cdate, datevalue etc but cannot trap 41/Jan/19 as an invalid date - it gets read in as 19/1/41 which is a valid date.

How can I ensure that 41/Jan/19, 30/Feb/20 6/Fbc/21 are recognised as unacceptable values?

Comment: You could use two textboxes and a combo-box.  Combo-box for the month, textboxes for day and year.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that the date is really entered the way you want, you could use an own VBA function:
**(o)** Split the entered input into 3 pieces. This can be done with the `Split`-function.
**(o)** Check if the string had 3 pieces
**(o)** Check that the piece for day and year are numeric
**(o)** Check that the piece for month is either numeric or a valid month name
**(o)** Use `DateSerial` to create a date from the pieces.
**(o)** Compare day, month and year of the generated date with day, month and year that where entered.

The following shows how this function could look like. I have declared it as `Variant` and return `empty` if the date is invalid - you can also declare it as `Date`, in that case it would return 0 (= 30 Dec 1899) for an invalid date. There is room for improvement, eg allow other separator characters like `-` or `.` (simply use a replace function to convert those to slashed) or handle space characters in the input. Also, the helper function handling the month will work only when the month name is entered with the correct regional settings - on my computer, for example, I display the date in german and therefore need to enter `MÄR` for march.

```
Function getdate(s As String) As Variant
    getdate = "(invalid)"
    
    Const separator = "/"
    Dim tokens() As String
    Dim dd As Long, mm As Long, yy As Long
    tokens = Split(s, separator)
    If UBound(tokens) <> 2 Then Exit Function           ' Syntax wrong (not exaclty two /-characters found)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    dd = CInt(tokens(0))
    mm = CInt(tokens(1))
    If mm = 0 Then mm = getMonth(tokens(1))             ' Handle Month Names
    yy = CInt(tokens(2))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If dd = 0 Or mm = 0 Or yy = 0 Then Exit Function    ' At least of the pieves was not a number
    If yy < 100 Then yy = Year(DateSerial(yy, 1, 1))    ' When 2-digits year, make it 4 digits
    
    Dim d As Date
    On Error Resume Next
    d = DateSerial(yy, mm, dd)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If d = 0 Then Exit Function                         ' Error creating date
    
    If (Day(d) <> dd Or Month(d) <> mm Or Year(d) <> yy) Then
        Exit Function                                   ' Invalid numbers in the input date
    End If
    getdate = d
End Function

Function getMonth(mm) As Long
    ' Convert month name to month number
    ' Returns 0 if invalid month name
    ' (Note: works only for the current regional setting)
    Dim d As Date
    On Error Resume Next
    d = CDate("20/" & mm & "/2023")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If d = 0 Then
        getMonth = 0
    Else
        getMonth = Month(d)
    End If
End Function
```

N.B.: If I where you, I would encourage everyone to enter years in 4-digits. Always - independently of the application.